# What happens if we (perversely) ask the interpreter to evaluate the combination f(f)?

Tags: python, function, lambda

```
def f(g):
    return g(2)

def square(x):
    return x ** 2
```

```
>>> f(square)
4
>>> f(lambda z: z * (z + 1))
6
>>> f(f)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

My Explanation:

I think in `f(g)`, `g` as an argument has to be a function, such that the lower level function can be called with a argument of g=2. However as `f(f)` is calling itself as a function, as previously mentioned, `g` has to be an function. However, `f(2)` is not callable. Hence resulting in an error.

I am unsure on whether I explained fully on why argument `g` has to be an function. And on whether I am explaining the problem in full.

Comment: I think you mean `g=2` makes `g` not-callable as it is an integer.

Comment: If you're unsure of that operation, then your next step is to check your details.  Insert `print` commands to display types and values, especially as the first statement in `f`.  You can get a little more information if you divide the final statement into `result = g(2); return result`.

Comment: I can't see **a problem** per se in evaluating `f(f)` in general case. E.g. with `def f(g): return g` there is no problem to `f(f)`. Problem starts only when you return non-callable from `f`

Comment: There is no problem *returning* a non-callable from `f`. But since `f` *invokes* the callable it receives as its argument, passing a specific value (`2` in this case) as the argument of that invocation, the callable argument `f` receives needs to behave correctly when given that value. That may be true for many callable values in practice, but not for `f` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` is a function that takes one argument, `g`, which must be a *callable* that can be applied to an `int`. That is, using the type hinting syntax from the `typing` module, we could say:

```py
def f(g: Callable[int, T]) -> T:
    return g(2)
```

Does `f` itself have type `Callable[int, T]`? No. An `int` is not a `Callable[int, T]`. So `f(f)` is an invalid application; if you were using a tool like [Mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) it should catch this.

At runtime, type hints aren't actually checked. But the runtime types still affect each other in the same way.

Calling `f(f)` results in the following invocations:

- `f(f)` means `g` is `f`, and results in a call to `f(2)`
- `f(2)` means `g` is `2`, and results in an attempt to evaluate `2(2)`

Applying the `()` operator to `g` means invoking the `__call__` special method, but an `int` does not implement `__call__`. Therefore you get the error message you describe:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```